# PhP Fatal Error: Cannot use string offset as an array when i add values to a json

Tags: php, json, prestashop

i have a JSon Array, and i would like to add (not edit) values, but when i try to add it, i get a fatal error.

Here is my code:

Error happens on the first **$ext_data['order']['lang_iso']=$lang->iso_code;**

```
$ext_order = array(
                    "order" => $order,
                    "order_detail" => getList($order->id),
                    "order_messages" => Message::getMessagesByOrderId($order->id),
                    "customer" => $customer,
                    "address_delivery" => $address_delivery,
                    "address_invoice" => $address_invoice,
                    "iso_codes" => $iso_codes,
                );
        
        
$ext_data = json_encode($ext_order, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR);
        
$ext_data['order']['lang_iso']=$lang->iso_code;
$ext_data['order']['carrier_name']=$carrier->name;
$ext_data['order']['ccurrency_iso']=$currency->iso_code;
$ext_data['customer']['lang_iso']=$lang_customer->iso_code;
$ext_data['address_delivery']['country_iso']=Country::getIsoById($address_delivery->id_country);
$ext_data['address_delivery']['state_iso']=$state_delivery->iso_code;
$ext_data['address_invoice']['country_iso']=Country::getIsoById($address_invoice->id_country);
$ext_data['address_invoice']['state_iso']=$state_invoice->iso_code;
```

Comment: You have to add to it before encoding, not after.

Answer (score 2):

```
   $order = json_decode(json_encode($order), true);   

   $ext_order = array(
                        "order" => $order,
                        "order_detail" => getList($order->id),
                        "order_messages" => Message::getMessagesByOrderId($order->id),
                        "customer" => $customer,
                        "address_delivery" => $address_delivery,
                        "address_invoice" => $address_invoice,
                        "iso_codes" => $iso_codes,
                    );
    
            
    $ext_order['order']['lang_iso']=$lang->iso_code;
    $ext_order['order']['carrier_name']=$carrier->name;
    $ext_order['order']['ccurrency_iso']=$currency->iso_code;
    $ext_order['customer']['lang_iso']=$lang_customer->iso_code;
    $ext_order['address_delivery']['country_iso']=Country::getIsoById($address_delivery->id_country);
    $ext_order['address_delivery']['state_iso']=$state_delivery->iso_code;
    $ext_order['address_invoice']['country_iso']=Country::getIsoById($address_invoice->id_country);
    $ext_order['address_invoice']['state_iso']=$state_invoice->iso_code;
    
    $ext_data = json_encode($ext_order, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR); // changed the order.
```

Comment: I tried like that the first time, but the error i get is: Cannot use object of type Order as array.

Comment: your $order variable is object not an array. Please turn it to array to use it. Like this: json_decode(json_encode($order), true); and put it into $ext_order

Comment: Or just use object syntax. `$ext_order['order']->lang_iso`